# Fully qualified name, unqualified name with import declaration resolve differently

Tags: f#

This works

```
open System
let f = Action(fun () -> Unchecked.defaultof<_>)
```

But this

```
let f = System.Action(fun () -> Unchecked.defaultof<_>)
```

produces the compilation error

> Multiple types exist called 'Action', taking different numbers of generic parameters. Provide a type instantiation to disambiguate the type resolution, e.g. 'Action<*,*,_,*,*,_,*,*,_>'.

I know I can fix it by adding a type parameter placeholder (`System.Action<_>(...)`), but any idea why they behave differently?

#### EDIT

Found this in the spec, section 14.1.9:

> When a module or namespace declaration group `F` is opened, items are added to the name environment as follows:
>
> - Add the type to the *TypeNames* table. If the type has a CLI-mangled generic name such as `List'1` then an entry is added under both `List` and `List'1`.

Is this behavior replicated for fully-qualified types (with omitted type parameters)? It doesn't appear so.

Comment: Regarding `new`, note that when you use `new` to call a constructor you always have to provide the right number of generic arguments (e.g. see what happens when you use `open System.Collections.Generics; new Dictionary()` as opposed to just `Dictionary()`.  This means that in your second edit, you are definitely calling the non-generic `System.Action` constructor rather than the `System.Action<unit>` constructor.

Comment: @kvb: Ah, yes--forgot about that. I'll remove it from the question since it's irrelevant.

Comment: @Daniel Are yiou using .NET 3.5 or .NET 4.0? I'm thinking that this Connect Bug, https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/482934/f-unable-to-correctly-resolve-non-generic-type-when-generic-type-exists-with-the-same-name, may be related to your problem if you're not using 4.0.

Comment: @James: This is .NET 4.0, but the issue looks similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with @James that this is related to the bug submitted on Connect, but I think it is a slightly different case. Anyway, I think this is not the intended behaviour. Could you report it to *fsbugs* at *microsoft* dot *com*?

Anyway - I did some debugging and here is what I found so far:

It seems that the compiler uses different code paths to resolve the name `Action` and the name `System.Action`. When resolving the other, it searches all loaded modules (i.e. assemblies) for a type named `System.Action` (see `ResolveLongIndentAsModuleOrNamespaceThen` function in the [`nameres.fs` file](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/nameres.fs) of the open-source release).

This finds the two definitions of `Action` (one in `mscorlib` and another in `System.Core`). I think the issue comes from the fact that the name resolution simply iterates over the results - it finds the first one (from `System.Core`), which doesn't have a usable overload (because it ranges from `Action<_,_,_,_,_>` to a version with about 15 type parameters). After finding this type, it reports an error without even looking whether there is another type (in another assembly) that could be used.

If you don't reference system assemblies, then the F# compiler resolves the overload just fine. Running the compiler without parameters references the default assembly set, so this doesn't work:

```
fsc test.fs
```

but if I add the `--noframework` flag, then it compiles without issues:

```
fsc --noframework test.fs
```

Comment: Thanks for doing the legwork to explain this. I've submitted a bug report.

Comment: @Daniel and Tomas: was there any follow-up to this? It [continues to cause confusion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27666242/4191347) as of F# 3.1.2, and I don't see anything on qualified names on the Codeplex issue tracker. It seems the bug report was not addressed. *Which is a little sad, given that this question will soon be three years old.*