# How to convert F# function to non-generic System.Action?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, f#

Just as in title. I have an existing C# library, and I must access it using F# interop. One of the methods takes a non-generic `System.Action` delegate as a parameter. How can I convert F# function (i.e. `unit->unit`) to that delegate?

While trying to use direct cast, a following error occurs:

```
Multiple types exist called 'Action', taking different numbers of generic parameters. 
Provide a type instantiation to disambiguate the type resolution, e.g. 'Action<_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_>'.
```

Comment: Can you show the exact code you're trying to use?

Comment: You cannot cast `System.Action` to `System.Action<T>`, they are unrelated.

Comment: It's solved. For some reason code `System.Action(fun () -> ())` is **always** trying to call generic version of Action delegate while pure `Action(fun () -> ())` is calling a non-generic one.

Comment: This is weird. It only happens when omitting the `new` keyword: `new System.Action(fun () -> ())` doesn't seem to throw the error. But it seems very unintuitive that the way the namespace is referenced would change the behavior! *I think this is a noteworthy observation; I don't see why the question would be voted to negative score.*

Comment: Note that you can always supply an explicit type parameter list to disambiguate, even in the non-generic case: just use `System.Action< >` (with a space inside the angle brackets).

Comment: [Oh wow: Daniel has already brought this up in 2012.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8732769/4191347) BTW @kvb I think your last comment would make a good answer to this question, since it looks like a proper way to annotate it. *I suppose the space is needed so it isn't parsed as the inequality operator?*